# CSS prevent menu from changing position

Tags: css

Someone asked me to improve his CSS to prevent the navigation menu from changing position when the browser gets smaller, but I can't figure out why it won't work. See the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gtvTY/10/

The HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" title="Home">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="virage.html" title="Virage">VIRAGE</a></li>
        <li><a href="rapide.html" title="Rapide">RAPIDE</a></li>
        <li><a href="dbs.html" title="DBS">DBS</a></li>
        <li><a href="db9.html" title="DB9">DB9</a></li>
        <li><a href="cygnet.html" title="Cygnet">CYGNET</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the original menu:

```
        ul.menu {
        position:absolute;
        left:18%;
        right:18%;
        background: #333;
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 64%;
        z-index: 3;
    }
    ul.menu li {
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    ul.menu a {
        background: #333;
        color: #ccc;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    ul.menu a:hover {
        background: #666;
        color: #fff;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
    }
```

I have redesigned it a bit to this. But it doesn't work at all...

```
#menu ul {
        position: absolute;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #menu li
    {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0.15em;
    }

    #menu li a
    {
        background-color: #333;
        height: 2em;
        line-height: 2em;
        float: left;
        width: 9em;
        display: block;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #menu ul a:hover {
        background: #666;
        color: #fff;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
    }
```

Why doesn't this menu stay centered at all times?

Comment: Please consider putting up an example on a website like http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: It is positioned absolutely.  If you want to center it you should give the menu a fixed width and use `margin: 0 auto;`  Also you posted the same code for both the original and your improved version...

Comment: Where's the rest of the code? We need more than the CSS. Add the HTML, and if you're nice add a jsfiddle too.

Comment: @Jrod, thx I have restored the original code. I will post the HTML and create a jsfiddle now ;)

Comment: @Jrod, if I remove the position:absolute the menu items won't show as a link when I hover over them. I think that has to do something with the rest of the CSS. Therefore I added all the CSS to the jsFiddle so you can have a look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is something like this you are looking for - jsFiddle in comment

Comment: Well thank you, this solution puts the menu in center position and it doesn't move when resizing the window ;) The only thing is.. it does nothing when I hover over the menu items. The browser doesn't see them as a link. I can only get the hover function back when I use position:absolute again, but that will ruin your whole design :( Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't work on jsFiddle for you? Or is it when you implement it into the rest of your code? - If it's the second - you should probably show all code possible

Comment: Maybe your desing conflicts with something in the other part of my css? You can find all the CSS in my jsFiddle

Comment: I'm not sure I see all the CSS - is a link missing?, I only see one jsFiddle link, and that's the code I changed to make my jsFiddle

Comment: Sorry, I didn't update the link the the new version of the js fiddle. It should be working now

Comment: Works fine in my browsers (IE+Chrome) - menu stays in middle + hover effect appears + edit: (works in FF as well)

Comment: how is that possible lol. Hover doesn't work here in IE,FF and Chrome :O

Comment: I'm stumped, no idea! My best advice: reboot :)

Comment: Have to close a lot then lol ;) I will try and remove cache files first. If that doesn't work I will reboot. I'll let you know if it works ;)

Comment: I'm sorry daniel but I have rebooted and cleared all cache, but still doesn't work

Comment: I'm really confused then - perhaps you should ask a new question where this is the main question, to me: http://jsfiddle.net/gtvTY/10/ works 100%

Comment: lol wait, I've added one postion:relative in #menu ul and now it works like a charm ;) Thx daniel!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the menu in a wrapping container. Give it a width and set the margin: 0 auto;

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewHenderson/gtvTY/7/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" title="Home">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="virage.html" title="Virage">VIRAGE</a></li>
            <li><a href="rapide.html" title="Rapide">RAPIDE</a></li>
            <li><a href="dbs.html" title="DBS">DBS</a></li>
            <li><a href="db9.html" title="DB9">DB9</a></li>
            <li><a href="cygnet.html" title="Cygnet">CYGNET</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>    
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
}
```

Comment: I can't see how this is different from what I already have now. Check the html and css in my jsFiddle.

Comment: It seems you have changed the jsFiddle link you provided. I commented on http://jsfiddle.net/gtvTY/. You're now linking to http://jsfiddle.net/gtvTY/10/. Please keep everyone informed of your updates otherwise we're all looking at different fiddles. Based on the responses, I think the question needs further clarification. I am not sure what it is you want to happen with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtvTY/9/)

1. Menu canter aligned in the bowoser.
2. Menu Items will not go in the second row.

if this is so the solution is

You have to use position:relative; instead of position:absolute;

```
<div class="center">
 <div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" title="Home">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="virage.html" title="Virage">VIRAGE</a></li>
        <li><a href="rapide.html" title="Rapide">RAPIDE</a></li>
        <li><a href="dbs.html" title="DBS">DBS</a></li>
        <li><a href="db9.html" title="DB9">DB9</a></li>
        <li><a href="cygnet.html" title="Cygnet">CYGNET</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​

and define a width to your menu css

```
.center
{
 width:auto;   
}
#menu
{
width:900px;
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;

}
#menu ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #menu li {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0.15em;
    }

    #menu li a {
        background-color: #333;
        height: 2em;
        line-height: 2em;
        float: left;
        width: 9em;
        display: block;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #menu ul a:hover {
        background: #666;
        color: #fff;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
    }
```

​